# Numpy : How do I create a meshgrid inside a box?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, 3d

I have a cuboid with all its eight corner vertice coordinates

```
(-111.2433, -70.9316, -26.2690)
(-111.2433, -70.9316, 80.8608)
(-111.2433, 71.5288, 80.8608)
(103.3007, 71.5288, -26.2690)
(103.3007, -70.9316, -26.2690)
(103.3007, -70.9316, 80.8608)
(103.3007, 71.5288, 80.8608)
```

I want to create 3D voxels inside this volume with a volume of *1m x 1m x 1m* and save their center coordinates. I tried to use `np.meshgrid()` for doing this as follows.

```
x_max = -1000000 
y_max = -1000000 
z_max = -10000000
x_min = 1000000 
z_min = 1000000 
y_min = 10000000 
for v in vertices:
    x = v[0] 
    y = v[1]
    z = v[2]
    x_max = max(x_max  ,x)
    x_min = min(x_min , x)
    y_max = max(y_max  ,y)
    y_min = min(y_min , y)
    z_max = max(z_max  ,z)
    z_min = min(z_min , z)
xdim = list(range(int(x_min) , int(x_max) , 1))
ydim =list(range(int(y_min) , int(y_max) , 1))
zdim =list(range(int(z_min) , int(z_max) , 1))
grid  = np.array(np.meshgrid(xdim , ydim , zdim)).T.reshape(3 , -1)
```

`xdim`,`ydim`,`zdim` are lists comprising of all the coordiantes which lie in the box dimension-wise and `np.mehsgrid()` basically takes the cartesian product of all these cooridnates giving hence giving us `(x , y, z)` cooridnates of all voxel centres which looks something like this.

```
array([[-111,  -70,  -26],
       [-111,  -64,  -26],
       [-111,  -57,  -26],
       ...,
       [ 103,   55,   80],
       [ 103,   62,   80],
       [ 103,   71,   80]])
```

What I think is that my implementation might be inefficient, so any help would be helpful!

Comment: Could you post a small sample of vertices?

Comment: @Ethan the vertices which I am iterating in here are basically the 8 corner vertices of the cube/box. I am taking the maximum and minimum possible coordinates in all 3 dimensions and making a mesh grid out of them ,basically a cartesian product of all 3 lists `xdim , ydim ,zdim` .The vertices (corner points) are : `(-111.2433, 71.5288, -26.2690)
(-111.2433, -70.9316, -26.2690)
(-111.2433, -70.9316, 80.8608)
(-111.2433, 71.5288, 80.8608)
(103.3007, 71.5288, -26.2690)
(103.3007, -70.9316, -26.2690)
(103.3007, -70.9316, 80.8608)
(103.3007, 71.5288, 80.8608)`

Comment: please edit your original post to include the example vertices. It will make things easier for anyone looking into your problem

Comment: @DrBwts I have updated my question accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

If you convert vertices to a numpy array of type int64 the can be greatly simplified:

```
def mgOriginal():
    vertices = [(-111.2433, 71.5288, -26.2690),(-111.2433, -70.9316, -26.2690),(-111.2433, -70.9316, 80.8608),(-111.2433, 71.5288, 80.8608),(103.3007, 71.5288, -26.2690),(103.3007, -70.9316, -26.2690),(103.3007, -70.9316, 80.8608),(103.3007, 71.5288, 80.8608)]
    x_max = -1000000 
    y_max = -1000000 
    z_max = -10000000
    x_min = 1000000 
    z_min = 1000000 
    y_min = 10000000 
    for v in vertices:
        x = v[0] 
        y = v[1]
        z = v[2]
        x_max = max(x_max  ,x)
        x_min = min(x_min , x)
        y_max = max(y_max  ,y)
        y_min = min(y_min , y)
        z_max = max(z_max  ,z)
        z_min = min(z_min , z)

    xdim = list(range(int(x_min) , int(x_max) , 1))
    ydim =list(range(int(y_min) , int(y_max) , 1))
    zdim =list(range(int(z_min) , int(z_max) , 1))
    grid  = np.array(np.meshgrid(xdim , ydim , zdim)).T.reshape(3 , -1)
    return grid


def mgNew():
    vertices = np.array([(-111.2433, 71.5288, -26.2690),(-111.2433, -70.9316, -26.2690),(-111.2433, -70.9316, 80.8608),(-111.2433, 71.5288, 80.8608),(103.3007, 71.5288, -26.2690),(103.3007, -70.9316, -26.2690),(103.3007, -70.9316, 80.8608),(103.3007, 71.5288, 80.8608)], dtype=np.int64)

    mins = np.min(vertices, axis=0) 
    maxs = np.max(vertices, axis=0)
    xdim = np.arange(mins[0] , maxs[0])
    ydim = np.arange(mins[1] , maxs[1])
    zdim = np.arange(mins[2] , maxs[2])
    grid  = np.array(np.meshgrid(xdim , ydim , zdim)).T.reshape(3 , -1)

    return grid
```

Proof of validity:

```
>>> a = mgOriginal()
>>> b = mgNew()
>>> np.all(a==b)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely safe some lines and more importantly computation.
I assume you have your vertices in an array, so you can make use of the `np.max` and `np.min` functions to search for the extreme values along the 0-axis.

I guess you want to enclose the cuboid entirely within the voxel-grid so I suggest you use `np.ceil` and `np.floor` for the inclusive rounding to the next index and the `.astype(np.int)` casting to make sure you can use the values as indices directly.

Finally your `np.meshgrid` creation is quite fine, for your special case of 1-increments you can also directly use `np.mgrid` with the index selectors

```py
x_max, y_max, z_max = np.ceil(np.max(vertices, axis=0)).astype(np.int)
x_min, y_min, z_min = np.floor(np.min(vertices, axis=0)).astype(np.int)
grid = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max, z_min:z_max].reshape(3,-1).T
```

hth; cheers